# Not able to retrive and update data in same struts action class

Tags: struts

I am new to struts and currently working on a project. In one page I want to populate some data from database and there is a submit button is available in my from  which will submit the data.

My struts action class is:

```
public class BookreturnAction extends org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        BookreturnForm bookreturnForm = (BookreturnForm) form;
        System.out.println("in the from" + bookreturnForm.toString());
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        List bookreturncollectionlist = new ArrayList();
        List<StudentSessionObjectStore> list = new ArrayList<StudentSessionObjectStore>();

        int studentid = 0;
        if (session.getAttribute("getsessionObject") != null) {

            list = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("getsessionObject");
            for (StudentSessionObjectStore store : list) {
                studentid = store.getId();
                System.out.println("the student id" + studentid);
            }

            bookreturncollectionlist = BookreturnDAO.getBookReturn(studentid);//use to papulate data
            request.setAttribute("collectionreturn", bookreturncollectionlist);
        }
        return mapping.findForward(Constants.ACTION_FORWARD_SUCCESS);
    }

    public ActionForward inserted(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                                  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        BookreturnForm bookreturnForm = (BookreturnForm) form;

        boolean isInserted = BookreturnDAO.bookReturn(bookreturnForm);//use to insert data
        if (isInserted) {
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Your Request Succesfully Submitted");
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Try again");
        }

        return mapping.findForward(Constants.ACTION_FORWARD_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Struts configution:

```
<action name="BookreturnForm" parameter="inserted" 
        path="/bookreturn" scope="request" validate="false"
        type="com.rec.bookbank.action.BookreturnAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/jsp/Student/bookReturn.jsp"/>
</action>
```

the link of my jsp page is

```
<html:link page="/bookreturn.do?parameter=inserted"> Books Return</html:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions, please describe what actually happens, and what steps are being taken to get to the bits that don't work. Is there an exception? Is the incorrect method being called? Is *no* method being called? Is there no data in the form? And so on.

It *looks* like you're clicking the link and expecting something to happen other than going to a new page. All you're showing is clicking a link--not submitting a form. Anything touching the action form isn't going to do what you think it is. In order to get form data, you must submit a form.

**On the code itself**

What is the loop over `StudentSessionObjectStore` doing? If there's only one item in the list then it's fine, but misleading: if there's a single student, keep it in session as a single student, not a list.

If there *is* more than one, then you'll always be returning the book returns for the last student (?) in the list. That's not *necessarily* wrong, but it seems like it *should* be wrong.

Consider using method and variable names to describe functionality, rather than comments. For example:

```
boolean isInserted = 
    BookreturnDAO.bookReturn(bookreturnForm); // use to insert data
```

This contains a couple of suspicious names, indicated by the necessity of the comment. Instead do this:

```
boolean wasReturned = BookReturnDao.returnBook(bookReturnForm);
```

Methods should generally be named as a verb indicating what the method does on a *conceptual* level. The action doesn't need to know implementation details; it doesn't matter if the book return process is handled with an insert, and it might change (setting a flag, deleting a record, etc.) Individual system components should know as little as possible about implementation details.

Similarly, don't pass Struts-specific classes, like an `ActionForm`, to the data layer. This ties the underlying code to the Struts framework, and makes testing more complicated without a good reason. Use something domain-specific, not framework-specific, instead, such as a book ID.